# rails : how can I use find_each with map?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, find, each

I have a form that has nested field (habtm and `accepts_nested_attributes_for`). That form contains with a field "keywords", that autocompletes keywords that come from a postgresql table.

All that works well. This is in params :

```
"acte"=>{"biblio_id"=>"1",  "keywords"=>{"keywords"=>"judge, ordeal, "}
```

What I now need to do is take those keywords and get their keywords_id out of the table keywords. Those id must be added to the join table.

I'm doing this :

```
q = params[:acte][:keywords].fetch(:keywords).split(",")
a = q.map {|e| Keyword.find_by keyword: e }
```

As per the guides, `find_by` returns only the first matching field. I guess I would need to use `find_each` but I'm not certain about that and I can't get it to word. I have tried this:

```
q = params[:acte][:motclefs].fetch(:motclefs).split(",")
a = Array.new
Motclef.where(motcle: q).find_each do |mot|
  a << mot.id
end
```

This also finds only the first result like : `[251]`.

What I'm looking to get is something like `[1453, 252, 654]`

thanks !

Answer (score -1):

Putting find_by in a loop means you will be executing a separate SQL query for each SQL keyword.

You can instead just get all the ids in a single SQL call by doing `keyword in`.

After you do `q = params[:acte][:keywords].fetch(:keywords).split(",")`, your `q` will be an array of keywords. So `q` will be `["judge", " ordeal"]`.

You can simply do `Keyword.where(keyword: q).select(:id)` which will generate a query like `SELECT keywords.id FROM keywords where keyword in ('judge', 'ordeal')`.